# Cannot see perl script on webpage (correct in CMD)

Tags: apache, perl, httpd.conf, centos6.5

My Perl program works correctly from the command line but not as a web page.

Here is my script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<title> PERL CGI</title>\n";
print "<body>";
print "hello perl-cgi!!!!!!!";
print "</body>";
print "</html>\n";
```

Error on wepbage is: `Internal Server Error`

Error from error log:

> ```
> [Tue Oct 04 10:04:41 2016] [error] [client 172.23.40.113] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/html/test2.pl' failed
> [Tue Oct 04 10:04:41 2016] [error] [client 172.23.40.113] Premature end of script headers: test2.pl
> ```

Here is a part of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```xml
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options ALL
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl  </Directory>
```

These are the contents of the `www/html` directory

```
786875 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16     3.Â ĹĂ­j     10.54 incex.html 
786669 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 22     27.Â zĂĄĹ   10.00 index.html 
786688 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 21     3.Â ĹĂ­j     08.47 info.php 
786899 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2765   3.Â ĹĂ­j     14.51 test.pl 
786834 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 161    3.Â ĹĂ­j     15.36 test2.cgi 
786833 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 259    4.Â ĹĂ­j     11.43 test2.pl
```

Comment: Is test2.pl executable? Check the permissions.

Comment: Also try using `print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  223  4.Â ĹĂ­j 11.10 test2.pl

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"; does not work

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/perl` the correct path for the server's perl executable?

Comment: What operating system are you testing this on? What operating system did you write this program on? If the answers are "Linux" and "Windows" respectively, you may have line-ending problems, specifically on your shebang line. Try running `dos2unix` on the program file.

Comment: Also worth checking if your server has a security error log. You might have `suexec` configured so that CGI programs need to be owned by the Apache user.

Comment: 2 Dave Cross, Both CentOs (linux)

Comment: I'd like to say that this is a very well-written question. The problem is clear, and all of the important information has been provided concisely. Well done.

Comment: 2 Borodin. I am so sorry I am new in linux... this is my firts server.. How to check it? in directory /usr/bin/ is only file perl.. is ti correct?

Comment: I should point out that the `<title>` element should properly be contained within a `<head>` element, but most browsers won't mind, and it won't cause the issue you're seeing here.

Comment: @user3456607: It sounds fine. Is this a private server? Try `which perl` just to confirm.

Comment: I edited file but problem persists. I thin, there will be problem between httpd/apache and PERL but I have no idea where...

Comment: @Borodin  which perl returns: /usr/bin/perl so it seems correct..
it is server in local network in my work

Comment: I suspect it's down to `suexec`. Look at other files in the www/html directory and ensure that your file is owner by the same user and group.

Comment: `786875 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   16  3.Â ĹĂ­j 10.54 incex.html
786669 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   22 27.Â zĂĄĹ 10.00 index.html
786688 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   21  3.Â ĹĂ­j 08.47 info.php
786899 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2765  3.Â ĹĂ­j 14.51 test.pl
786834 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  161  3.Â ĹĂ­j 15.36 test2.cgi
786833 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  259  4.Â ĹĂ­j 11.43 test2.pl`
Root only.. html, php are correct, problem only with .pl a .cgi

Comment: Perhaps [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39848005/edit) to add information like this. It's hard to read in comments.

Comment: And try looking in `/var/log/secure` for more hints.

Comment: @DaveCross its empty (there is only info about connection via ssh2, nothine more)

Comment: @Borodin — The start and end tags for the head element are explicitly optional in the HTML spec.

Comment: @Quentin: If you want to use those options then you must prefix your data with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Borodin — Browsers don't treat optional start and end tags for the head element any differently in quirks mode.

Comment: As I recall, and it's been a loooong time since I did anything like this, permissions can cause all sorts of problems in these circumstances. What are the permission on your directory (not the file, the directory)? What user and group are allowed in httpd.conf, and do they have access to the resources? Are your line endings (file line endings) correct for the platform you are using? Does test.pl run okay, and if so, what are the differences between that and test2.pl? What do you see in suexec logs?

Comment: @PerlDog: What is all of this about? I also said in the same comment *"it won't cause the issue you're seeing here"*. I was commenting on traditional well-formed HTML and no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help..
now it works.. problem was very simple (and stupid). I did not see it in nano.. my script started on second line.. so it was not start with #!/usr/bin/perl